# Getting error while implement indicator on a SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2012, iif

Trying to write an expression to implement indicator on a SSRS report, but keep getting an error on the last nested iif statement

Problem is in the last nested iif statement.

```
   iif(Fields!Focus_Area.Value ="Spares",(iif(Count(Fields!Focus_Area.Value) > 0,0,1)),
   iif(Fields!Focus_Area.Value ="Orders,(iif(Count(Fields!Focus_Area.Value) > 3,0,1)),
   iif(Fields!Focus_Area.Value ="Sales",(iif(Count(Fields!Focus_Area.Value) > 6,0,1),"N/A")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems likely to be a datatype conversion error.  You are returning integers for the output in most cases, but in one case you are returning a string ("N/A") which cannot be cast as an integer.

You should have the expression return string values of the integers (e.g., "3" vs. 3) or change the N/A condition to return Nothing or some integer.  Which method you choose should be determined by how you're using the output of the expression.